# How do I know what to set sourceCompatibility vs targetCompatibility to?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

according to MoPub Docs I should add this to my gradle file, but my question is what do I pick for sourceCompatibility and target compatibility, it seems like target Compatibility has to be set to 1_8 or else it will not build.  But what is the difference if I leave sourceCompatibility to 1_7 vs 1_8 is there a way to know which one my project uses, sourceCompatibility builds the app fine with either one set I would just like to know what is the difference between the 2 and if I actually do need to set it to 1 of them instead of the other also I've read that gradle uses the java version which is on our machine and mine is 1.8.0 so why do I have to explicitly declare VERSION_1_8 ?

on java docs it states "Generates class files that target a specified release of the virtual machine. Class files will run on the specified target and on later releases, but not on earlier releases of the JVM. Valid targets are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), 1.7 (also 7), and 1.8 (also 8)." but java 1.7&1.8 not available on android 4.1 and it still runs on android 4.1 when I set java version to 1.7 or 1.8 how is this possible ?

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    } }
```

Comment: Source compatibility: the version the software was written for, or a later one if it still compiles. Target compatibility: the lowest Java version you are intending to support in the field.

Comment: how is target compatibility the lowest java version we intend to suppport if its 1.8 and software was written in 1.7 its still going to work in 1.7

Comment: @user207421 do you know why my android project uses java 7 if i have JDK 8 installed on my machine ? it uses java 7 by default before i even set the source & target compatibility